# dropdown in WP elementor won't close

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am bilding a site in WP Elementor. 
on mobile version dropdown menu opens, but won't close when tap on item. 
Is there some tweak i can do? 
I have tried some script, but when I put that in functions.php I got error 505, won't render. please help :)

script:

```
 <script>
 var closeMenu = function() {
      var menu = document.querySelector(".elementor-menu-toggle");
      var menuItem = document.querySelector(".elementor-item");
      menuItem.addEventListener("click", menu.removeClass("elementor-active");
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you have x button to close menu. My problem was that it was covered by menu. Option "Distance" in 
Dropdown section of menu was like -50, so i could not see close button.

Comment: Question for auto closing menu (not with button) still stays. If someone knows how to pull that, please tell!